Выставить фильтр на выборку файлов в имени которых не более одной точки
for file in glob.glob(patch+'*.*'):

Таким образом, выбираем из папки все файлы в имени которых есть точка. Проблема в том, что может захватить тот файл который в процессе загрузки.
К примеру, закидывают файл размером в 10 гб. Система дает ему временное имя
news.mp4.filepart

То есть данный файл, пайтон тоже прихватит. Собственно вопрос, как выставить фильтр на то, что в имени должна присутствовать точка и в количестве 1шт.

Архивы вида program.tar.gz очень сильно обижаются на ваш костыльный подход

Да и тот же python-3.12.6-amd64.exe тоже недоволен

1)Как вариант - использовать count для подсчета количества вхождений подстроки в строке, а дальше любое условие на свой вкус..
def valid_name(filename):
    if filename.count('.') == 1:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

file_name = "news.mp4.filepart"
file_name2= "news.mp4filepart"

valid_name(file_name) # False
valid_name(file_name2) # True


2)Если все файлы переименовываются пока закачиваются и получают расширение .filepart, тогда всё просто..
def valid_name(filename):
    
    if filename.endswith('.filepart'):
        print("False")
    else:
        print("True")

file_name = "news.mp4.filepart"
file_name2= "news.mp4"

valid_name(file_name) #False
valid_name(file_name2) #True


3)Вообще, надо поэкспериментировать, и попытаться открыть файл который ещё  загружаются! По идеи он должен быть ещё заблокирован и выбьет ошибку. Обрабатываем исключение и не добавляем его в список файлов‍♀️

4)Как вариант можно пройтись по всем файлам в каталоге дважды и сравнить значения при первом проходе со вторым. Те что в размере не увеличились те в список и добавляем.

В линуксах (наверно и в маках тоже) блокировки файлов нету

А сравнение размера выдаст ой если интернет подвиснет)

@andreymal Хорошо, ваши идеи?)

А нету их ¯\(ツ)/¯

@andreymal если все файлы переименовываются пока закачиваются и получают расширение .filepart, тогда всё просто.. filename.endswith('.filepart')

filename.endswith('.filepart'), хороший, рабочий вариант. К имени файлу добавляется приставка filepart когда загружаю через терминал WinSCP. Если загружаю через сайт, файла в каталоге нету, появляется тогда когда целиком загружен. Собственно вопрос, oc ubunto, пока файл не загружен целиком, он временно в каком месте размещается?  Если загружаем через сайт, или я что то путаю?
